# How do I transform xml from axis2 services using jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xslt, xslt-1.0, apache-axis

I'm running into a problem with axis2 and ajax. I'm getting xml from one of my web services with jQuery's ajax functions, and using [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Transform) jquery plugin to transform the result xml to html.

Here's an example of the relevant xml that the service returns.

```
<ns:getPatientsByDoctorResponse>
    <ns:return type="com.emolst.jdbc.PatientBean">
        <ax23:firstName>Bryce</ax23:firstName>
        <ax23:lastName>Thompson</ax23:lastName>
    </ns:return>
</ns:getPatientsByDoctorResponse>
```

I looked through the xml Document object that I get from the jQuery ajax call, and it seems to have stripped the namespaces from the tags and made the tags all lowercase. However, I can't seem to get my xsl templates to recognize any of the tags.

Here's what I have now in the xsl.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <option>success1</option>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//return">
        <option>success2</option>
        <option>
            <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/> <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
        </option>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The best I can get is the success1 option. I found some info [here](http://www.marcusschiesser.de/?p=142) about making axis2 play nicer with ajax, but that looks like it might screw up the java service clients I have.

Here's the javascript in question.

```
$("select[name=patientlist]").transform({
    xml:{
        url:"/axis2/services/PatientService/getPatientsByDoctor",
        data {
            docKey: "6"
        },
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"xml"
    },
    xsl:"xsl/patients-option.xsl"
});
```

So am I doing something stupid or is there a better way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you tell where the error was after all? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you think namespaces are gone, but I think they are not. Why should they?

Try a transformation that ignores namespaces, like this:

```
<xsl:transform 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <option>success1</option>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='return']">
        <option>success2</option>
        <option>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='firstname']"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='lastname']"/>
        </option>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

or a template that uses them correctly, like this:

```
<xsl:transform 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ax23="........ax23 namespace here........"
  xmlns:ns="........ns namespace here........"
>

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <option>success1</option>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns:return">
        <option>success2</option>
        <option>
            <xsl:value-of select="ax23:firstname"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ax23:lastname"/>
        </option>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Awesome! The first solution works beautifully. I might try the second one later.

Comment: The second one with correct namespace usage might perform better on the long run. And it sure as hell is easier to manage. Of course you *can* write XPath expressions that are all local-name(), but it is neither fun nor very readable.